# Split sub images is error in openCV

Tags: c++, opencv

I have an image of text that consists of multiple lines and is in Thai. I want to split the image into separate lines of text, and I can check the number of lines. The problem is that when I split the sub images it generates an error.

**My code**

```
vector<int> point;
//Function Check Line
int checkLine(cv::Mat imgSrc){

    int temp=-1;
    int line=0;
    int CountI[32767], CountJ[32767];
    int countRange=0;
    int maxBlack = INT_MIN;

    point.clear();

    for(int y=0;y<imgSrc.size().height;y++)
     {
        for(int x=0;x<imgSrc.size().width;x++)
        {
            if(imgSrc.at<uchar>(y,x)==0){
                //cout<<y<<":";
                if(y-temp>1){
                    point.push_back(temp);
                    point.push_back(y);
                }
                temp=y;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    point.push_back(temp);
    point.erase(point.begin(), point.begin()+1);

    for(vector<int>::size_type i = 0; i<point.size(); i++){
        CountI[i]=point[i];
    }

    for(vector<int>::size_type j = 0; j<point.size()-1; j+=2){
        CountJ[countRange++]=point[j+1]-point[j];
    }

    for(int i=0;i<countRange;i++){
        if(CountJ[i]>maxBlack) maxBlack=CountJ[i];
    }

    for(int i=0;i<countRange;i++){
        if(CountJ[i]>(maxBlack*0.5)) line++;
    }

    return line;
}


//Function Line Rect 
vector<cv::Mat> lineRect(cv::Mat imgSrc, vector<int> startPoint, vector<int> stopPoint)     {
    vector <cv::Mat> img_split;
    img_split.clear();
    for(vector<int>::size_type k = 0; k<startPoint.size(); k++){
        img_split.push_back(imgSrc(cv::Rect(0,startPoint[k],     imgSrc.cols,stopPoint[k]-startPoint[k])));
    }

    return img_split;
}    

int main()
{
    const string path = "D:\\\exam.jpg";
    cv::Mat img_src = imread(path,0);
    vector<cv::Mat> img_split;
    cv::Mat img_tmp;
    vector<int> startPoint;
    vector<int> stopPoint;
    vector<int> PBlackFont;
    vector<int> PBlackBack;
    vector<int> pointW;
    int line=-1;
    int check=-1;


    line = checkLine(img_src);
    int textLine = line;
    for(int k=0;k<textLine;k++){
        cout<<line<<endl;
        if(check==1){
              img_tmp = imread("D:\\buff\\tmp1.jpg",1);
        }
        else if(check==2){

            img_tmp = imread("D:\\buff\\tmp2.jpg", 1);
        }
        else if(check==-1){
            img_tmp = img_src;
        }

        if(line>1){
            PBlackFont.clear();
            PBlackBack.clear();
            pointW.clear();
            for(int i = 1; i<point.size()-1; i+=2){
                pointW.push_back((point[i+1]-1)-(point[i]+1));
                PBlackFont.push_back(point[i+1]-1);
                PBlackBack.push_back(point[i]+1);
            }

            int max=INT_MIN, index=-1;
            for(int j = 0; j<pointW.size(); j++){
                if(pointW[j]>max) {
                    max=pointW[j];
                    index=j;
                }
            }

            startPoint.clear();
            stopPoint.clear();
            startPoint.push_back(point[0]);
            startPoint.push_back(PBlackFont[index]);
            stopPoint.push_back(PBlackBack[index]);
            stopPoint.push_back(point[point.size()-1]);

            img_split.clear();
            img_split = lineRect(img_tmp, startPoint, stopPoint);
            if(img_split[0].size().height>img_split[1].size().height){
                char buff[3];
                std::string nameindex = itoa(1, buff, 10);
                std::string name = "crop "+nameindex;
                cv::imshow(name, img_split[1]);
                cv::imwrite("D:\\Buff\\tmp1.jpg", img_split[0]);
                img_tmp = imread("D:\\Buff\\tmp1.jpg", 1);
                cv::imshow("Crop1", img_tmp);
                line = checkLine(img_tmp);
                check=1;
            }
            else {
                char buff[3];
                std::string nameindex = itoa(2, buff, 10);
                std::string name = "crop "+nameindex;
                cv::imshow(name, img_split[0]);
                cv::imwrite("D:\\Buff\\tmp2.jpg", img_split[1]);
                Mat img_tmp = imread("D:\\Buff\\tmp2.jpg", 1);
                cv::imshow("Crop2", img_tmp);
                line = checkLine(img_tmp);
                check=2;
            }
        }  
        else {
            startPoint.push_back(point[0]);
            stopPoint.push_back(point[point.size()-1]);

            char buff[3];
            std::string nameindex = itoa(3, buff, 10);
            std::string name = "crop "+nameindex;
            cv::Mat img_t = img_split[0];
            img_split = lineRect(img_t, startPoint, stopPoint);
            cv::imshow(name, img_split[0]);
        }
    }
```

**The error**

`Unhandled exception at 0x74dd969b in test.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: cv::Exception at memory location 0x0014ed88..`

and

**in console**

`OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (0 <= roi.x && 0 <= roi.width && roi.x + roi.width <= m.cols && 0 <= roi.y && 0 <= roi.height && roi.y + roi.height <= m.rows) in unknown function,file ..\..\..\src\opencv\modules\core\src\matrix.cpp, line 323`

Comment: Could you post a minimal working example or at least a version that compiles? "point" is undefined in your code. An image file would also be nice.

Comment: My image file [link] http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/838/wwwgv.png)

Comment: This can be split into three sub-images.

Comment: 1) The code still doesn't work despite your edit. Point has no elements when it is called in the main function. 2) What I meant by minimal working example is that you should try to reproduce the error in less than the 200 (!) lines you currently have if you want someone to read your code. Did you try stepping through the code with a debugger? At which line does the error appear? Are the other 200 lines really necessary? The error is thrown during an OpenCV command, try to eliminate the vector and counting operations from your code first.